# Debian 10のbashシェルで$ sudo apt updateを行うとエラーが出ます。

Tags: linux, bash, debian, apt

お世話になります。
Debian 10のbashシェルで`$ sudo apt update`を実行しますと、エラーが出ますので解決したいです。
以下はターミナルのメッセージです。

```
$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Hit:2 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian buster InRelease                               
Hit:3 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian buster-updates InRelease                                         
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]                                 
Ign:5 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:6 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                         
Hit:7 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch Release               
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Hit:9 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease                   
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu focal Release               
 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

それから、Ubuntuのリポジトリは削除しまして、`/etc/apt/sources.list`の記述を下記のようにいたしましたが、それでもエラーが出ます。以下は`/etc/apt/sources.list`のUbuntuのリポジトリを削除したあとの記述です。

ちなみに、なぜUbuntuのリポジトリを追加したのかと言いますと、fingerprint-guiをインストールしたかったからなのです。

```
#
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.2.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20191116-09:56]/ buster main
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.2.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20191116-09:56]/ buster main
deb http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
# fingerprint-gui
# Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20170722-11:29]/ stretch main
deb http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

それから`$ sudo apt update`を実行しましたところ、下記のエラーが出ました。

```sh
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Hit:3 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian buster InRelease                                                         
Get:4 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]                                       
Ign:5 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                           
Get:6 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]                                                                         
Hit:7 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                                                                     
Ign:8 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                             
Hit:9 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                   
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu focal Release               
 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease     
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

上記のエラーを解決したいです。皆様ご教授よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-focal.list` というファイルが存在しませんか？

Comment: Debian公式ドキュメントの[sources.list - APT のデータ取得元の設定リスト](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/sources.list.5.ja.html)
に「`/etc/apt/sources.list.d` ディレクトリは、別々のファイルで source.list のエントリを追加する方法を提供します。次の二つの節で説明するように、二つの異なるファイル形式が許可されています。」と書いてあるのを発見致しました。
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-focal.list `というファイルがあるかどうかを見てみます！

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-focal.list`を削除しましたら、`$ sudo apt update`を実行してもエラーが出なくなりました。ありがとうございました！

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/226716

Comment: htb様
違うサイトに同じ投稿をするのはマナー違反でしょうか？
teratailでは満足の行く回答が返ってこなかったので、このような対応を取らせていただきました。
不快な思いをさせて申し訳ございません。

Comment: SOでのマルチポストの扱いについては[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)を御覧ください。（マルチポスト即ち悪ということはないです）

Comment: それから今後同じ疑問を持ってこのサイトを訪れる方のためにも、ぜひ解決策を自己回答の形でまとめていただけたら有り難いです。

Comment: letrec様 色々とありがとうございます。
teratailで解決策を得られましたら、自己回答の形でまとめさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-focal.list` を削除しましたら、
`$ sudo apt update` を実行してもエラーが出なくなりました。

**補遺**

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` 以下に置かれているファイルには APT リポジトリに関する情報が記載されていますが、通常、これらのファイルは `add-apt-repository` コマンドを利用して追加・削除します。

今回の fingerprint-gui パッケージの場合は [Fingerprint GUI](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui) の Installation に記載がありますが、以下の様にします(root 権限で実行)。

```shell
## 追加
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui

## 削除
$ sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
```

「削除」と書きましたが、実際にはファイル(`fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-focal.list`)の内容が全て削除されてファイル自体は残ります(いわゆる truncate)。

Comment: > metropolis様
補遺ありがとうございます。とてもわかりやすいです！