# Ubuntu20.04.2 で apt-get update をしようとするとエラーになってしまい解決出来ない

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

表題のとおりなのですが、ターミナルで下記コマンドを入力したところ、エラーが発生しました。

```sh
$ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                       
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease
Get:6 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease [23.5 kB]   
Err:6 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C6ABDCF64DB9A0B2
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C6ABDCF64DB9A0B2
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

上記のエラー解決のために以下2点行いました。

(1)Slackの削除
インストーラーにしてインストールしていたGUIのSlackアプリを削除しました。
上記のエラーに影響はなく、という状態です。
※いずれにしろSlackは必要なのでこの解決策で解決したとしても問題ですが…

(2)apt-keyコマンドを用いた解決の試み
[How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)を参考に下記コマンドを入力しました。

```
sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  <PUBKEY>
sudo gpg -a --export <PUBKEY> | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

※はいずれもエラー表示の値、C6ABDCF64DB9A0B2に置き換えて入力済です。

入力後の表示は下記です。

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key C6ABDCF64DB9A0B2
gpg: key D938EC0D038651BD: "https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack (https://packagecloud.io/docs#gpg_signing) <support@packagecloud.io>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

$ sudo gpg -a --export C6ABDCF64DB9A0B2 | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.IDoHc58igN/home:manuelschneid3r.asc.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 7
gpg:       skipped new keys: 7
```

上記いずれのやり方でも全く解決せず、という状態です。
アドバイス・回答いただけますと幸いです。

[追記 8/29(日)]
aptやdpkgでインストール済のパッケージを確認したところ、slackは入っていません。

```
$ apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | grep slack
$ dpkg -l
```

他参考記事
[Debian 10のbashシェルで$ sudo apt updateを行うとエラーが出ます。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61103/debian-10%e3%81%aebash%e3%82%b7%e3%82%a7%e3%83%ab%e3%81%a7-sudo-apt-update%e3%82%92%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e5%87%ba%e3%81%be%e3%81%99)
[Key not found on keyserver or keyserver not accessible](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/18927)
[apt-get update giving error in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348284/apt-get-update-giving-error-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しましたのでここに記載します。

まずSlackをaptを用いてインストールすることは諦め、(1)リポジトリ(2)リポジトリリスト(3)GPGキーを削除することにします。

(1)に関しては質問に記載したようにaptでもdpkgでも確認されなかったため、どうやらアンインストール済のようです。

(2)に関しては、

```
$ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
$ ls
google-chrome.list  home:manuelschneid3r.list slack.list
$ sudo rm  slack.list
```

にて対応。

(3)に関しては、

```
$ sudo apt-key list
```

にて該当のGPGキーがないためそもそも存在していない？と思われます。

以上を終えて`sudo apt update`をしたところ無事出来ました。

[参考]
 [Ubuntuで不要になったリポジトリを削除する](https://vild.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/06/02/141430)

Comment: slackはaptではなくsnapコマンドを用いてインストールしました。参考：https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-slack-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop